# Field status need to select dynamically from child to parent

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

My scenarios is that Opportunity and section are in master detail relationship.  Section status is a picklist field on section object with the following values

```
1-won
2-In-market
3-Won/Mandated
4-Issued Commitments
5-Pipeline
6-Proposal Pending Risk Appr
7-Proposal Early Stage
```

Requirement scenarios

1. Opty got too many sections
2. need to show in opty record with section status picklist value(i.e,
   based on priority) eg: from  section records descending order value
   need to pick from section status and update in opty. suppose that
   record gets deleted then next descending order value need to be
   update in opty.  For this I created a statusupdate custom field in OPty.

I am hoping to get help with coding logic for querying and update functionality.

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself or would you just like that someone helps you with coding?

Comment: for this just give idea like how to map with opty and section and querying and update functionality..

Answer (score 0):

While I will not just write the code for you, I will try to help get you started and point you in the right direction.

On thing that was unclear in the question was when you say that section object is is descending order.  Ordered by what field?

For a solution to your problem you would....

- Write a trigger on the Section__c object.
- This trigger is an after trigger as it needs to perform an update on
  another database object (Opportunity).
- When the trigger is fired, it takes the opportunity that the section
  is related to, and queries for all Sections that are related to that
  Opportunity.
- Within that query, you can order it by whichever field you would like
  in descending order.
- Now that you have your list, you need to look at the first value in
  the list, list[0], and take that status field, and copy it to the
  opportunity custom status field.
- Then you could update the opportunity and you are done.

Here is a sample of what I am talking about.

> NOTE: This trigger below is not efficient and goes against many best
>   practices (not bulkified at all, logic directly inside the trigger, etc.).  This was on purpose.  This is meant to be a rudimentary example of a very simple
>   trigger.  It is not meant to be copied and used as it will not be
>   efficient.  It is meant to give you a simple idea of the solution,
>   then you can use the reference material I provided below to build off
>   it and make use best practices to make it more efficient.

```
trigger mySectionTrigger on Section__c (after insert) {

         Opportunity opp = [Select Id, Name Custom_Status__c 
                             From Opportunity 
                             Where Id =: trigger.new[0].Opportunity__c;

         list<Section__c> allSections = [Select Id, Name, Status__c 
                                          From Status__c 
                                          Where Opportunity__c =: opp.Id
                                          Order By someCustomField__c desc];
         opp.Custom_Status__c = allSections[0].Status__c;
         update opp;
}
```

Here are some great resources on writing triggers to try to help you implement what I have suggested above.  I hope this gives you a great start on coding your solution.  Good luck.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs_HelloWorld.htm

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices

http://techman97.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/how-to-write-a-basic-apex-trigger/

http://rainforce.walkme.com/how-to-create-a-trigger-in-salesforce/#.UtZ4emRDulo